# Delete specific numbers characters from Excel cell counting backwards

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an Excel sheet where my column B has following combination of words and letters

(Name Lastname 3to4Numbers PM/AM Month date Year)

Example:

- Kevin Hart 206PM May 16 2020
- Michael B Jordan 0339AM May 06 2020

I want to go in each cell in my B column and remove the 3 to 4 Numbers and the pm or Am.

I thought about counting backwards and remove position 13 to 20 since the names will vary.

Any other ideas and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I realize you might now have it in pandas yet. If you don't, you do somethe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('YOURFILE.CSV')
```

And then you run the line under the `#Solution` in the code below, change `col` to the name of your column, and `col2` to whatever you want your new column to be called. You can save your file again with `df.to_csv('outputfile.csv')`. Good luck!

Here is a solution using Regex.

```
# Sample data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['Kevin Hart 206PM May 16 2020',
            'Michael B Jordan 0339AM May 06 2020',
           ]
})

# Solution
df['col2'] = df['col'].str.replace('\s\d{3,4}[AP]M', '')

print(df)

                                   col                          col2
0         Kevin Hart 206PM May 16 2020        Kevin Hart May 16 2020
1  Michael B Jordan 0339AM May 06 2020  Michael B Jordan May 06 2020
```

Comment: Nice, but why a comma in `[A,P]` character class? +

Comment: In Regex, that means "either A or P". So you're maching both AM and PM.

Comment: See what it does when you remove the comma. Right now your character class means: ***or*** A ***or*** comma  ***or*** P. It wouldn't matter for the data at hand. But the comma is redundant =)

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen if i have my data in coloumn B how do i read them in one by one instead of manually typing them in?

Comment: `df['new_column'] = df['B'].str.replace('\s\d{3,4}[AP]M', '')`. Edit: Updated my answer.

Comment: Think you are missing something there Shawn.

Comment: Oh sorry, what i meant was right now i can print the edited data frame but it saves the original version instead of the edited in the new file?

Comment: Well you're making a mistake when saving it. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using VBA:

before:

[image]

the code:

```
Sub TimeKiller()
    Dim cell As Range, arr, s As String, a As String
    Dim i As Long

    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        s = cell.Value
        If s <> "" Then
            arr = Split(s, " ")
               For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    a = arr(i)
                    If a Like "###AM" Or a Like "###PM" Or a Like "####AM" Or a Like "####PH" Then
                         arr(i) = ""
                     End If
                Next i
        End If
        cell.Value = Trim(Join(arr, " "))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In windows Excel 2016+, with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"& SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(contains(.,'AM')) and not(contains(.,'PM'))]"))
```

[image]